We control API Gateway using AWS Lambda
We are going to use AWS Gateway's API Key.
We would like to issue a new API Key when registering as a member.
The logic I came up with is to register an appropriate Lambda function for the membership request (POST).
However, we are new to using Lambda functions.
Is there a way to access API Gateway's functionality through a Lambda function?
For example, creating an API key or registering usage, etc.
I am Korean and wrote this with the help of Google Translator.
Here is our current status:
Create an API in API Gateway and create an endpoint HTTP registration and usage plan.
However, we are unable to automate API key generation.

Check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway-readme.html#adding-an-api-key-to-an-imported-restapi.
